# Detecting UIImagePicker opened or not from a web view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

In my project I am having a web view. The page loaded in the web view contains an file (Image) uploader. On clicking the choose image button on the file uploader, then the phone's image picker opens. I am not authorised to make changes in the web page, because it is client organisations web page. Is there any way to detect the opening of UIImagePicker in the app.

```
<input id=“fileUpload" name=“fileUpload" type="file" data-bind="value: UploadedFile">
```

This is the html used for the file picker. On clicking the file picker the UIImage Picker View pops up. I want to detect it.

Comment: did you find something on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the web page, for ‘Choose Image’ Button write a Java Script function . iOS supports custom URL schemes provided with syntax below

> scheme://host/path?query

Example Java script function in your .html  :

```
 <p class="btn-upload" onclick="onUploadButtonClick()" >
    <span>  Upload File </span> 
</p>

<script>

    function onUploadButtonClick() {

        window.location = "ios://button-upload”;

    }

</script>
```

In your class .m file, inside Webview delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request:navigationType` compare the host. if it matches invoke your objective c function to open UIImagePicker in the app.

```
#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegates

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    //Do after web view load.
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{

    // get the action from the path
    NSString *actionType = request.URL.host;

    if ([actionType isEqualToString:@“button-upload”]) {
        // do something in response to your javascript action
        // if you used an action parameters dict, deserialize and inspect it here

        [self  openImagePicker]; //Cal your method to open UIImagePicker

    }

    // make sure to return NO so that your webview doesn't try to load your made-up URL
    return NO;
}
```

Bonus : Make sure you have added [App Transport Security Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31807139/3632832) in your `info.plist`.

Comment: I am not authorised to make any change in the web page. It is client organisation's web page. Is there any way to detect the picker only in the app side logics?

Comment: Okey, then  can you please share the `html` lines that related button actions?

Comment: Also don't forget to try [Jockey.js](https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs) may be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: @RikudouSennin you don't need to change the source of the web page, simply inject JavaScript into the web view when it loads (i.e. in `webViewDidFinishLoad`). Use [stringByEvaluatingJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617963-stringbyevaluatingjavascript) to inject the JavaScript.